# Create Circle tangent to two lines with radius r [geometry]

Tags: geometry, sympy, lines

I want to put a circle between two lines However, I only want to use one line for the creation of the circle.
So my approach is to select points on line 1.
For each point on line 1:
I want to create circles with increasing radius which are tangential to the point 1 on line. Increase the radius, until the circle intersects also the other line. Decrease afterwards the radius in smaller steps until the circle is tangential to both lines.
Proceed with next point on line 1.

Somehow, I am not able to find a clean and crisp code to do that. The points on the line can be done using  line.arbitrary_point.
How can I create a circle with radius R to the point p1 so that it is tangential in the best way?

Thanks!

Comment: Description of your approach is vague. What do you really want to get as result? How sympy is useful here? Perhaps a picture might make things more clear...

Answer (score 10):

The center of a circle of radius `R` that is tangent to two lines `s1` and `s2` is the intersection of two other lines, each one is parallel by a distance `d= R`

[image]

Let line `s1` from `A1= {ax1,ay1}` to `B1= {bx1,by1}` and `s2` from `A2= {ax2,ay2}` to `B2= {bx2,by2}`

Using parametric representation, a point in `s1` is

```
s1x= ax1 + k1·v1x
s1y= ay1 + k1·v1y
```

where `k1` is a different value for each point and `{v1x,v1y}` is *unitary* vector in direction `A1,B1`:

```
le1 = sqrt((bx1-ax1)^2 + (by1-ay1)^2) //length of A1-B1 segment
v1x = (bx1-ax1) / le1
v1y = (by1-ay1) / le1
```

Same goes for line `s2`:

```
s2x= ax2 + k2·v2x
s2y= ay2 + k2·v2y
with
le2 = sqrt((bx2-ax2)^2 + (by2-ay2)^2) //length of A2-B2 segment
v2x = (bx2-ax2) / le2
v2y = (by2-ay2) / le2
```

Now, to get a parallel to `s1` we just change point `A1` by adding a vector `vp1`  perpendicular to A1-B1 with length `d= R`. The perpendicular unitary vector is: `vpu1= {-v1y, v1x}`. **Attention**: if you want the other solution, at the other side of both lines, then use `{v1y, -v1x}` instead.

So, with `vp1 = vpu1·R` and `vp2= {-v2y, v2x}·R` the new points for parallels to `s1` and `s2` are

```
px1= ax1 - v1y·R
py1= ay1 + v1x·R
px2= ax2 - v2y·R
py2= ay2 + v2x·R
```

Now we must find the intersection `C` of theses lines:

```
sp1x= px1 + k1·v1x
sp1y= py1 + k1·v1y
sp2x= px2 + k2·v2x
sp2y= py2 + k2·v2y
with
sp1x = sp2x
sp1y = sp2y
```

Solving for `k1, k2, sp1x, sp1y` we get:

```
den = v1x·v2y - v2x·v1y
k1 = (v2y·(px2-px1) - v2x·(py2-py1)) / den
k2 = (v1y·(px2-px1) - v1x·(py2-py1)) / den
cx = px1 + k1·v1x   =   px2 + k2·v2x   //choose one
cy = py1 + k1·v1y   =   py2 + k2·v2y   //choose one
```

**Pay attention** to the value of `den`. It `abs(den) < smallValue` (IOW, this denominator is close to zero), then `s1` and `s2` are parallel or the same straight. In this case, there isn't a solution.

Finally, the tangent points are now easy:

```
tx1 = ax1 + k1·v1x
ty1 = ay1 + k1·v1y
tx2 = ax2 + k2·v2x
ty2 = ay2 + k2·v2x
```

Comment: Hmmm .. there are for a given radius R and two intersecting lines FOUR different solutions for cx, cy and the tangent points. How to get them out of the provided code?

Comment: See the remarked "Attention" in the paragraph starting with "*Now, to get a parallel...*" For each line you have two perpendicular unitary vectors (-vLy, vLx) and its opposed (vLy, -vLx). Depending of the sign you choose for each parallel, you get four combinations, corresponding to the four solutions.

Comment: Why not showing the options clearly in the answer? With code demonstrating returning of all the values? With such a nice image and explanations it would make the answer useful out of the box with providing the entire code in one piece easy to test if it does what it promises. Best with a turtle animation showing how it works ...