# Formulae / Method to calculate smooth curved line between two points satisfying headings of both points

Tags: python, math, formula, smoothing, curve

[image]
As shown in the image, formulae or method how to calculate smooth curved line is needed.The red line is the line which will look at the end after solving.

I'll appreciate your help / discussion.

I need mathematical formulae and may be how to solve it using scipy python package.

Comment: A Bézier curve should do it.

Comment: For that I need at least three points, correct? But I have only two points here.

Comment: So you create your own third point. Deliberately. Specifically, you position it at the point where the lines along those headings intersect. Then it will get the correct directions at the two ends. Note that the Bezier curve will be pulled toward, but not go through, that extra point, which is purely there to get the gradients right.

Comment: @JabedAkhtar You have two points *and two headings*. That's a lot more than *just two points*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create Circle tangent to two lines with radius r \[geometry\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223685/create-circle-tangent-to-two-lines-with-radius-r-geometry)

Comment: @Ripi2 The question you link starts with only two lines, but this question starts with two points and two headings, which is basically two points and two lines. There is no guarantee that a circle exists which is tangent to these two lines *at these two points*.

Comment: @Stef Heading and lines suggest a circle tangent to both lines, which likely will not match the "two points" requirement. Other curves may be parabola, hiperbola, bezier, a pair of clothoids or some degree polynomial. But the OP didn't tell about what kind of curve, that's why I supposed a normal roads design case.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you will gain more flexibility if you use cubic Bezier curves.

This for the first problem:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#-----------------------------

def length( vector ): return np.linalg.norm( vector )      # length of a vector
def normalise( vector ): return vector / length(vector)    # normalise a vector (numpy array)

#-----------------------------

class Bezier:
    '''class for Cubic Bezier curve'''
    def __init__( self, q0, q1, q2, q3 ):
        self.p0 = np.array( q0 )
        self.p1 = np.array( q1 )
        self.p2 = np.array( q2 )
        self.p3 = np.array( q3 )

    def pt( self, t ):
        return ( 1.0 - t ) ** 3 * self.p0 + 3.0 * t * ( 1.0 - t ) ** 2 * self.p1 + 3.0 * t ** 2 * ( 1.0 - t ) * self.p2 + t ** 3 * self.p3

    def curve( self, n ):
        crv = []
        for t in np.linspace( 0.0, 1.0, n ):
            crv.append( self.pt( t ) )
        return crv

#-----------------------------

def drawBezier( x1, y1, heading1, x2, y2, heading2, n ):
    '''Turns two points plus headings into cubic Bezier control points [ P0, P1, P2, P3 ] by adding intermediate control points'''
    result = []

    rad1, rad2 = heading1 * math.pi / 180, heading2 * math.pi / 180
    d1 = np.array( [ np.sin( rad1 ), np.cos( rad1 ) ] )    # direction vector at point 1
    d2 = np.array( [ np.sin( rad2 ), np.cos( rad2 ) ] )

    p0 = np.array( ( x1, y1 ) )                            # start point of Bezier curve
    p3 = np.array( ( x2, y2 ) )                            # end point of Bezier curve
    p1 = p0 + d1 * length( p3 - p0 ) / 2.0                 # use direction at P0 to get P1
    p2 = p3 - d2 * length( p3 - p0 ) / 2.0                 # use direction at p3 to get P2

    arc = Bezier( p0, p1, p2, p3 )                         # define a cubic Bezier object

    x = [];   y = []
    for pt in arc.curve( n ):
        x.append( pt[0] )
        y.append( pt[1] )
    plt.plot( x, y )
    
#-----------------------------

x1, y1, heading1 = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
x2, y2, heading2 = 1.0, 1.0, 90.0
drawBezier( x1, y1, heading1, x2, y2, heading2, 100 )
plt.plot( [ x1, x2 ], [ y1, y2 ], 'o' )                   # plot original support points
plt.show()
```

[image]

The advantage of the cubic Bezier is that you can also seamlessly deal with the cases such as where the two direction lines don't cross. For example

```
x2, y2, heading2 = 1.0, 1.0, 0.0
```

with output

[image]